# SQL query overlapping time undercounting

Tags: sql

I am writing a query that counts how many people were 18 months active on a certain day of each year.

The problem I'm having is that between the years there is an overlap in time period which causes the later years to be undercounted because they are classified as the previous year.

For example, '2017-03-06' could be considered activity for 2018 AND 2017.
Here is my query:

```
select case when deposit_dt between '2017-02-07' and date then '2018'
    when deposit_dt between '2016-02-07' and '2017-08-07'  then '2017'
    when deposit_dt between '2015-02-07' and '2016-08-07' then '2016'
    when deposit_dt between '2014-02-07' and '2015-08-07' then '2015'
    when deposit_dt between '2013-02-07' and '2014-08-07' then '2014'
    end as yr, count(unique(op_id))
    from activity_table
    where deposit_dt between '2013-02-07' and date
    group by deposit_dt
```

Any advice on how to get around this issue (other than running a new query for each year)?

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?  Is `unique` really a valid function?

Comment: How do you want to resolve the overlapping ranges?  To which range should an overlapping date be assigned, or maybe to both?

Comment: What does "18 months active mean?

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that you really want something along the lines of the following:

```
select
    count(case when deposit_dt between '2017-02-07' and date then 1 end) as 2018,
    count(case when deposit_dt between '2016-02-07' and '2017-08-07' then 1 end) as 2017,
    count(case when deposit_dt between '2015-02-07' and '2016-08-07' then 1 end) as 2016,
    count(case when deposit_dt between '2014-02-07' and '2015-08-07' then 1 end) as 2015,
    count(case when deposit_dt between '2013-02-07' and '2014-08-07' then 1 end) as 2014
from activity_table
where deposit_dt between '2013-02-07' and date;
```

Note that it doesn't make sense to group by `deposit_dt`, since this is the column which is being used to aggregate.

This assumes that you don't have logic beyond this to take the potentially overlapping dates into account.  If you can provide logic for how to resolve a date which matches more than one range, then the above query can be updated.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but I don't think this is exactly what he wants as if a user made multiple deposits, your query would count them multiple times

Comment: @Kevin Then let this answer force the OP to tell us what he wants to do :-)

Comment: I'd pivot it out just like @TimBiegeleisen did.  However I would name the output periods.  period1, period2, period3...because the users where I work would ask questions about the years and 18 months and drive me batty.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want.

```
select count(distinct [2018Users]) as [2018], count(distinct [2017Users]) as [2017],count(distinct [2016Users]) as [2016] 
from(
    select case when deposit_dt  between '2017-02-07' and date then op_id  end as [2018Users],
           case when deposit_dt  between '2016-02-07' and '2017-08-07' then op_id  end as [2017Users],
           case when deposit_dt  between '2015-02-07' and '2016-08-07' then op_id  end as [2016Users]
    from activity_table
    ) c
```